# Remove the same elements from two arrays Golang

Tags: arrays, go, intersection

`a:=[]rune("/storage/emulated/0/Custom_Scripts/Golang/")`

`b:=[]rune("/storage/emulated/0/")`

There are two slices a && b, within the cycle we should take each element from the second slice $b and compare it to the element from the first slice $a and if they are identical then we are removing this element from the first slice $a
The solution should be without any packages, except the fmt(only for print the final array) and by two way:
Fist with using the loop
Second over maps

Try to release it in this way, but I get the panic with out of range, can someone help to me please?

```
package main
import(
"fmt"
)
func main() {
    fileMeta := 
[]rune("/storage/emulated/0/Custom_Scripts/Golang/")
    delChr := []rune("/storage/emulated/0")
    for i, j := range fileMeta {
        for _, m := range delChr {
            if m == j {
               //fileMeta[i] = ""
               fileMeta = append(fileMeta[:i], 
fileMeta[i+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(fileMeta)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not reinvent the wheel:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fileMeta := []rune("/storage/emulated/0/Custom_Scripts/Golang/")
    delChr := []rune("/storage/emulated/0")

    fm := string(fileMeta)
    pfx := string(delChr)

    if tail := strings.TrimPrefix(fm, pfx); len(tail) != len(fm) {
        fileMeta = []rune(tail)
    }

    fmt.Println(fileMeta, string(fileMeta))
}
```

BTW, do you *really* need to operate on `[]rune`s? It's unnatural for most applications–why not use proper strings right away?

Comment: Thanks for solution! I apologize, but solution should be without any  additional package, only via loop and maps

Comment: @functionX, so, basically, it's a homework assignment, right? ;-)

Comment: it's a  interview exercise, that I was failed, so now solution of that is a matter of principal

Comment: is it possible solve that task without extra packages like strings and etc? I has interview for the Junior position, but in my personal opinion this task is for Middle level, because it's seems like is a rather complicated task

Comment: @functionX, OK, [here's](https://go.dev/play/p/wUCtx_u5_ZZ) one way to implement this.

Comment: @functionX, «is it possible solve that task without extra packages like strings and etc?»–this is a pretty strange question to ask: if you think about it, a string is a sequence of "somethings" (bytes in Go), so `strings.TrimPrefix` surely solves your task, it just does not operate on runes, but rather on bytes. Actually, you could have slices of any types whose values are comparable–this would not change the algorithm. Also, there exists `bytes.TrimPrefix` which operates on byte slices.

Comment: example of solution  with test coverage that's a really cool   Thanks! About solution without string package, I mean the native solution explain more clearn and obviously what's going on and how it works, thanks once again!

Comment: The problem is solved by the @kostix, solution is [here](https://go.dev/play/p/wUCtx_u5_ZZ)

Comment: @functionX, «example of solution with test coverage that's a really cool»–basically that's what that "TDD" thing is about: when you write a function which is unlikely to be ever changed after completion, consider immediately covering it with unit-tests, and start those tests with a set of edge cases (ideally–all you could come up with), because "normal" cases usually almost always work because that's what a typical programmer automatically thinks about when designing an algorithm.